# Sending email with attachment using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I know this is an old issue or concern but can you help me on this.

I have a source code found in the internet that can send an attachment via email. I tried it in my application but I getting this error.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x8000405) Invalid mail attachment C:\File.pdf  
at System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment.VerifyFile() 
at System.Web.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String filename)
```

This is the code I found

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Web.Mail
Public Class ReportsForm
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim pdfFile As String = "C:\File.pdf"
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cryRpt.Load("Crystal Report Path here")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
            Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
            DiskFileDestinationOptions()
            Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFile
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions
            With CrExportOptions
                .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
                .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
            End With
            cryRpt.Export()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        sendMail()
    End Sub
    Private Sub sendMail()
        Try
            Dim Smtp As SmtpMail
            SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "hostname")
            Dim Msg As MailMessage = New MailMessage
            Msg.To = "to address"
            Msg.From = "from address"
            Msg.Subject = "Crystal Report Attachment "
            Msg.Body = "Crystal Report Attachment "
            Msg.Attachments.Add(New MailAttachment(pdfFile))
            SmtpMail.Send(Msg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the computer let you open the file C:\File.pdf ? Is this an ASP.NET application, by any chance?

Comment: Hi, when I check my Local Disk C, there was no .pdf file. This is a VB.net application

Comment: As a Windows security feature, programs can't usually write to the root of C:. I suggest that you save the file somewhere like `IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "File.pdf")`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but when I tried this one, I'm still getting the error above. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did the PDF file get created there?

Comment: System.Web.Mail is deprecated. Use System.Net.Mail.

Comment: You should ALWAYS dispose the Attachments after sending the email.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, May I ask where to find the .pdf file to check if the system created this? Thanks

Comment: @Lawrencxe Please see the documentation for the [Path.GetTempPath Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath).

Comment: Re: "source code found in the internet" - do you have any understanding, what YOUR code does?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, checking the folder path, I can't find the file since I'm still getting the error above.

Comment: Hi @Arvo, yeah I understand what the code found does.

Comment: This is the error appeared when I update code to `IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "File.pdf")`

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\test.pdf'.`

Comment: @Lawrencxe At a guess, you need to change the line that declares the variable: `Dim pdfFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "File.pdf")`.

Comment: According to Crystal docs, don't you need to use report options as parameter to .Export() method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms226036(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your pdf attachment file. You are going to need somewhere safe to create it. You'll create the attachment file path and name using this code:

```
Dim pdfFile As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "File.pdf"
If System.IO.File.Exists(pdfFile) Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(pdfFile)
```

Then you'll export the cryRpt object to a pdf file using just one line of code:

```
cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdfFile)
```

If no exception occurs your attachment is created and ready to be mailed.